# Execute a plugin in Marketing List in Microsoft Dynamics 365

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365

When someone add multiples members (contacts, account, etc) to the Marketing List (entity name "list") I need execute a plugin. Now, I register the plugin with the "Plugin Registration Tool" on this messages (with entity "none") and I got:

- Message: **AddListMembers**: 
  Don't execute. In this, I set entity "list" too, but nothing change.
- Message: **AddListMember**:
  Don't execute.
- Message: **AddMember**:
  Executed two times (I add two contact in one time). Almost!!
- Message: **AddMembers**:
  Don't execute.
- Message: **Update**:
  Don't execute.
- Message: **Associate**:
  Don't execute.

How I can known what message is the correct or what is the name for the correct message?

Comment: Did it answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

[Guido's answer in the Dynamics community forum](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/microsoft-dynamics-crm-forum/220781/plugin-registration-tool-messages-for-marketing-list) clearly explains what we need to know:

> AddMember is called when a single record is added to the marketing
>   list
>
> AddListMembers is called when multiple records are added to the
>   marketing list
>
> PLEASE NOTE that when you add members to a marketing list using
>   certain ways (for example using advanced find query if I remember
>   correctly) that message is not triggered.